# How to synchronize datasource updates with tableview reloads with thread safety?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am getting frequent updates of the tableview datasource and need to synchronize tableview updates with datasource updates properly. Can you suggest the right approach to this in Swift 3?

**ListViewModel**

```
/// Main list viewmodel refreshing and filtering API
private func refreshCards(withIcon icon: CardIcon) {

    queue.async {

        Log.debug("refresh cards Started")

        switch icon {

        case .all:

            self.loadOpenCards()
            self.loadCompletedCards()

        default:

            self.filterOpenCards(byIcon: icon)
            self.filterCompletedCards(byIcon: icon)
        }

        // Ask list TVC to reload table
        self.listTVC?.refreshForUpdates()

        Log.debug("refresh cards Finished")
    }
}
```

**ListTableViewController**

```
func refreshForUpdates() {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.updateApprovalListBackgroundGraphics()

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        Log.debug("refresh cards Reloaded")
    }
}
```

In this code tableView.reloadData() does not wait for the viewmodel refresh because it is dispatched async on the main thread.

Comment: when are you calling refreshForUpdates() ??

Comment: Why does your model know about a view controller? That's backwards.

Comment: @Tushar Shama: In the view model after line // Ask list TVC to reload table

Comment: @rmaddy: Agree, I hear both options, viewmodel gets updates, or that viewcontroller get updates. Let's leave that for now, do you see a way to solve the thread synchronization? Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your issue? It seems you update the data source on the separate thread and then refresh the table view after the datasource is done refreshing. All looks good in the code that you posted. Explain what is your result and what is the expected result.

Comment: @MartinKoles You missed my point. Your model should be used. It should deal with updates. But it should not know about a specific view controller. Your model should be usable by any other class and it should be able to notify any number of classes that it has been updated.

Comment: We can discuss the MVVM pattern use here, but I would like to shift the focus on the actual quesiton I have. BTW, reference to listTVC is weak. The expected behavior is that printed log statements are in the sequence of: 1. refresh cards Started, 2. refresh cards Reloaded, 3. refresh cards Finished. Currently, the sequence is not guaranteed, sometimes Reloaded is logged before Finished, sometimes not. The danger here is that I get frequent updates (parallel downloads, user interaction) and the app can sometimes crash when the request object in datasource is removed/updated without sync with TV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general approach I take in cases like this is to ensure the view controller has a static copy of the data so nothing is being changed in the background.

You have a master instance of your data model. This data model processes asynchronous updates. What it needs to do is to notify its listeners (such as a view controller) that it has been updated. The listener should respond to this update by saving off a copy of the data model and then refreshing its views (such as reloading a table view).

If the master data model happens to post another update while the view controller is updating itself, it's not a problem since the view controller won't handle that next update until it finishes updating from the previous update and the view controller's copy of the data has not yet changed with the new update.

Comment: I was actually thinking of the 'copy' approach as well, but I found it extra work for a simple synchronization task between VC and its viewmodel. But I will now try it if I don't get any better suggestions. Thanks

Comment: The view controller needs a stable copy of it's data to ensure its views are in sync with the data. If the data can change while the view is being updated, you have problems (such as crashes). There is really no other choice than to make a copy if the master data is being updated regularly and asynchronously.

Comment: I agree and will try that now. I was actually thinking of another possible approach using queues - to enqueue requests for model updates into serial queue and execute them one by one synchronously with the tableview reload. That would mean to only start next model update refresh when the previouos completed including its tableview reload on the main thread. I know how to do this with NSOperation or ProcedureKit that I am using, but was not sure exactly how to do it with Dispatch (GDC) APIs directly in Swift 3. I would call the NSOperation/Procedure to finish when the tableview reload is done.